# "rails server", "rails db:migrate" stop working after "rails db:system:change --to=postgresql"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

Steps to reproduce:

1. `rails _7.0.4_ new test --skip-bundle`
2. set Gemfile (see below)
3. `bundle _2.3.14_ install`
4. initialize git + connect to github repo
5. `rails db:system:change --to=postgresql`
6. This changes "sqlite3" to "pg" in my Gemfile for reasons I do not know, so I change it back

Now when trying to run "rails server" the terminal output seems fine but when trying to connect to it via Microsoft Edge browser it just loads indefinitely. "rails server" works before step 6.

When doing "rails db:migrate" it is just stuck in infinite execution without error. See trace below.

Deploying it on Render.com works.

This is the whole project, I'll put it on private once I understand what is happening: https://github.com/Ferdodonna/sample_app

**Gemfile before step 6, after step 6 `gem "sqlite3", "1.4.2"` becomes `gem "pg", "1.4.2`**

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }
ruby "3.1.2"

gem "rails", "7.0.4"

gem "sassc-rails", "2.1.2"

gem "sprockets-rails", "3.4.2"

gem "importmap-rails", "1.1.0"

gem "turbo-rails", "1.1.1"

gem "stimulus-rails", "1.0.4"

gem "jbuilder", "2.11.5"

gem "puma", "5.6.4"

gem "bootsnap", "1.12.0", require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem "sqlite3", "1.4.2"
  gem "debug", "1.5.0", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
end

group :development do
  gem "web-console", "4.2.0"
end

group :test do
  gem "capybara", "3.37.1"
  gem "selenium-webdriver", "4.2.0"
  gem "webdrivers", "5.0.0"
  gem "rails-controller-testing", "1.0.5"
  gem "minitest", "5.15.0"
  gem "minitest-reporters", "1.5.0"
  gem "guard", "2.18.0"
  gem "guard-minitest", "2.4.6"
end

group :production do
  gem "pg", "1.3.5"
end
# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem.
# Uncomment the following line if you're running Rails
# on a native Windows system:
gem "tzinfo-data" #, platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

**Terminal output for "rails server" after step 6**

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 7.0.4 application starting in development
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
Puma starting in single mode...
* Puma version: 5.6.4 (ruby 3.1.2-p20) ("Birdie's Version")
*  Min threads: 5
*  Max threads: 5
*  Environment: development
*          PID: 10656
* Listening on http://[::1]:3000
* Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

**Termianl output for "rails db:migrate --trace" after step 6**

```
>rails db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
```

**Terminal output for aborting "rails db:migrate --trace" after step 6**

```
...
** Execute db:migrate
rails aborted!
Interrupt:
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/pg-1.3.5-x64-mingw-ucrt/lib/pg/connection.rb:627:in `wait_writable'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/pg-1.3.5-x64-mingw-ucrt/lib/pg/connection.rb:627:in `async_connect_or_reset'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/pg-1.3.5-x64-mingw-ucrt/lib/pg/connection.rb:707:in `new'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/pg-1.3.5-x64-mingw-ucrt/lib/pg.rb:69:in `connect'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:78:in `new_client'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:37:in `postgresql_connection'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:656:in `public_send'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:656:in `new_connection'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:700:in `checkout_new_connection'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:679:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:640:in `acquire_connection'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:341:in `checkout'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:181:in `connection'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_handler.rb:211:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:313:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:280:in `connection'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:262:in `migrate'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:92:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `synchronize'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:182:in `invoke_task'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:138:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:138:in `each'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:138:in `block in top_level'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:147:in `run_with_threads'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:132:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in perform'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:208:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:24:in `block in perform'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:59:in `with_application'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/command.rb:51:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y
```

I tried running `rails server` expecting to connect to the application locally.

I tried running 'rails db:migrate`, expecting it to just run through without doing anything, since I didn't implement any database structures yet.

I assume that it tries to connect to a postgresql database that doesn't exist and 'rails server' doesnt emulate. But I am new to Ruby as well as RubyOnRails so I am unsure. Is there a way around that?

Comment: I don't really understand why you want to switch to PostgreSQL (step 5) and change your Gemfile back in step 6.

Besides a look into config/database.yml could be helpful. Which database driver ist used there?

Comment: I didn't change my Gemfile "back". The switch to postgresql made a change to my Gemfile to get `gem "pg", "1.4.2"`. This gem doesnt exist with that version. Further, I already have pg im my Gemfile with the correct version. The line read `gem "sqlite3", "1.4.2"` before, which is correct. For whatever reason it replaces "sqlite3" with "pg", leaving the version number unchanged.

I'm using SQLite3.

Comment: Just to explain " For whatever reason it replaces "sqlite3" with "pg"" --> your step 5 did exactly this. You can (and should) just skip this step if you don't want to use PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a look at your config/database.yml on Github. There you have:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: sample_app_development
```

Which basically tries to connect to the nonexistent server on localhost. So you have to change this to something like

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Addionally you may want to change the version strings in your Gemfile:

```
 gem sqlite3, '~> 1.6'           #, "1.4.2" --> https://rubygems.org/gems/sqlite3/
 gem pg , '~> 1.5'               #, "1.3.5" --> https://rubygems.org/gems/pg/
```

as both gems have received several updates in the past.

Comment: Yes, now it doesn't loop infinitely when connecting to localhost, but gives me my root page.

I am doing the Rails On Ruby Tutorial 7, so I use the gem versions Micheal Hartl uses. Only since the deployment service he uses doesn't have a free plan, I use Render.com which requires you to set up your project and produces outcomes I currently don't understand. 

Thank You!